# Solve the inequality $\sqrt { x + 2} - \sqrt { x + 3} < \sqrt { 2} - \sqrt { 3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Solve for $x$ real the inequality $$\sqrt { x + 2} - \sqrt { x + 3} < \sqrt { 2} - \sqrt { 3}.$$ Obviously $x\ge-2$. After that I tried to square the whole inequality, which led me to $x < - \frac { 18} { 4\sqrt { 6} - 5}$. Now, the answer is $[-2;0) $. Should there be a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{ x + 2} - \sqrt{ x + 3} &< \sqrt{ 2} - \sqrt{ 3} \\
\sqrt{ x + 2}  + \sqrt{ 3} &<  \sqrt{ x + 3} + \sqrt{ 2}  \tag{1}\\
(x + 2)  + 3 + 2\sqrt{ 3}\sqrt{ x + 2}  &<  (x + 3) +  2 +2\sqrt{ 2}\sqrt{ x + 3} \tag{2}\\
2\sqrt{ 3}\sqrt{ x + 2}  &<  2\sqrt{ 2}\sqrt{ x + 3} \tag{3}\\
3(x + 2)  &<  2( x + 3) \tag{4}\\
x  &< 0 \tag{5}
\end{align}
where we

> $(1)$ added $\sqrt{ x + 3} + \sqrt{3}$
>
> $(2)$ squared both sides (they are positive)
>
> $(3)$ subtracted $x+5$
>
> $(4)$ divided by $2$ and squared (again both sides are positive)
>
> $(5)$ subtracted $2x+6$

Now just combine it with the condition $x\geq -2$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

If we differentiate, $\frac d{dx}(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+3})=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac1{\sqrt{x+2}}-\frac1{\sqrt{x+3}}\Big)>0$. So, provided $x\geq-2$, the LHS is continuous and increasing with $x$ and it will be equal to the RHS when $x=0$. Therefore it is less than the RHS when $-2\leq x<0$.

To see it is increasing without calculus, note that
$$\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+3}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+3}},$$
and the denominator is clearly increasing with $x$.

Comment: Regarding the first part: for the differention, you want $x>-2$, **not** $x\geq -2$. The function is not differentiable at $-2$.

Comment: @ClementC. Why did you delete your answer ?

Comment: @A---B Because (i) it does not abide by the request made by the OP, and (ii) Especially Lime's answer (after fixing the small flaw pointed out above) provides the same approach.

Comment: Yes, it's not differentiable at $-2$ but it is continuous at $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

First lets multiply the inequality by $-1$ so we can square. $$\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+3}<\sqrt2-\sqrt3\\\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x+2}>\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$$Now lets square$$2x+5-2\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}>5-2\sqrt{6}\\x+\sqrt6>\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}$$
Now since $x+\sqrt{6}\geq-2+\sqrt 6>0$ we can square the inequality again
$$x^2+2\sqrt{6}x+6>x^2+5x+6\\(2\sqrt6-5)x>0$$
This happens when $x<0$ since $2\sqrt6=\sqrt{24}<\sqrt{25}=5$ is negative so $x$ must be as well.

Comment: Since I accidently copied your answer I will just post it here as a note and delete my answer.$$\\$$ By multiplying with conjugate we get,

$${-1\over \sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x+2}} < {-1 \over \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}}$$

 $$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} > \sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x+2}$$. With this, on squaring, you get $x(5+2\sqrt{6}) < 0$. so $x<0$.

And since $x \ge -2$. We get the answer.